# "java.net.BindException: Address already in use" while trying to profile with Java VisualVM

Tags: java, exception, profiler, visualvm, jvisualvm

I'm trying to profile a java program with the Java VisualVM profiler on mac.

Part of the Message has been reported in the past [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455698/visualvm-profiler-error-class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-both-bin-ja) .

The exception I'm getting is the following:

```
objc[20398]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Profiler Agent: JNI OnLoad Initializing...
Profiler Agent: JNI OnLoad Initialized successfully
Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140 (Protocol version: 14)
Profiler Agent Error: Exception when trying to establish connection with client:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

I don't fully understand the error. Are there any possible solutions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have forgotten to close the serversocket in the catch clause. Try restarting your IDE and add serversocket.close in the catch.

Comment: I don't know , I don't use any serversockets. I run the program from command line.

Comment: Ok I see. It is obviously in use by another program as isaac.hazan said. But can you check the firewall to see which program uses the port?

Answer (score 0):

"Address already in use" means that you have another process that is already listening on port 5140.

Look if you have already the same process running or use a tool like http://alternativeto.net/software/portsmonitor/ to see which process already listens on port 5140

Comment: Is there a way that I can assign my program to a different port , because I don't use sockets, so maybe I could change VisualVM's ?

Comment: Even if you program does not use socket VisualVM does use it. There are certainly ways to assign it another port, you need to look in the doc of Visual VM and see how to change the port but IMO identifying the process that hold that port and killing is the easiest. It could even be that it diesn't work you because you mistakenly run the VisualVM twice